# Howto update auto-implemented (by convention) many to many in Entity Framework Core 6 (.Net 6)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, many-to-many

I use EF Core 6 (**not "classic" EF6**) in ASP .NET Core 6 Web App (Razor pages) and I have the following entites and context (simplified):

```
public class Task
{
   public Task()
   {
       PlaneTypes = new HashSet<PlaneType>();
   }

   public Int64 Id { get; set; }
   public String Name { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<PlaneType> PlaneTypes { get; set; }
}

public class PlaneType
{
   public PlaneType()
   {
       Tasks = new HashSet<Task>();
   }

   public Int64 Id { get; set; }
   public String Name { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}

public partial class PlanDbContext : DbContext
{
    public PlanDbContext()   {   }

    public PlanDbContext(DbContextOptions<PlanDbContext> options)
        : base(options)   {   }

    public virtual DbSet<PlaneType> PlaneTypes { get; set; }        
    public virtual DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
    //some other DBSets

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("data source=DBPlanov.db;Pooling=False;");
            optionsBuilder.ConfigureWarnings(w => w.Throw(RelationalEventId.MultipleCollectionIncludeWarning));
        }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
         modelBuilder.Entity<Task>().HasIndex(t => new { t.Name }).IsUnique();
         modelBuilder.Entity<PlaneType>().HasIndex(pt => new { pt.Name }).IsUnique();
    }
```

As you can see I have no distinct entity for many-to-many table (it is auto-implemented by EF Core 6 and I don't need to configure it - it is working without explicitly mapping the join table):

```
CREATE TABLE "PlaneTypeTask" (
    "PlaneTypesId" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "TasksId" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_PlaneTypeTask" PRIMARY KEY ("PlaneTypesId", "TasksId"),
    CONSTRAINT "FK_PlaneTypeTask_PlaneTypes_PlaneTypesId" FOREIGN KEY ("PlaneTypesId") REFERENCES "PlaneTypes" ("Id") ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT "FK_PlaneTypeTask_Tasks_TasksId" FOREIGN KEY ("TasksId") REFERENCES "Tasks" ("Id") ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE INDEX "IX_PlaneTypeTask_TasksId" ON "PlaneTypeTask" ("TasksId");
```

I have an ASP page to edit a Task where name and a list of PlaneTypes can be changed. My page model has:

```
[BindProperty]
public TaskEditModel CurrentTaskEditModel { get; set; }
```

where `TaskEditModel` is:

```
public class TaskEditModel
{
   public Task Task { get; set; }

   //some other properties
}
```

In code-behind I get edited task data from database with the following code:

```
public PartialViewResult OnGetShowTaskEdit(Int64 taskId)
{
     CurrentTaskEditModel = new();
     CurrentTaskEditModel.Task = _context.Tasks.
     Include(t => t.PlaneTypes).AsSplitQuery().SingleOrDefault(t => t.Id == taskId);
     ...
     return Partial("_TaskEditPartial", CurrentTaskEditModel);
}
```

After task is edited I save it with the following code:

```
...
if (TryValidateModel(CurrentTaskEditModel.Task))
{
     using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
     {
          try
          {
               //Option1: NOT working - PlaneTypeTask table is NOT filled
               _context.Attach(CurrentTaskEditModel.Task).State = EntityState.Modified;

               //Option2: NOT working also - SqliteException (SQLite Error 19: 'UNIQUE 
               //constraint failed: PlaneTypeTask.PlaneTypesId, PlaneTypeTask.TasksId')
               _context.Update(CurrentTaskEditModel.Task);

               await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
               transaction.Commit();              
           }
           catch
           {
               transaction.Rollback();
           }
}
...
```

So load a Task with one PlaneType in its list. And I try to save it with edited name and with another PlaneType added to a list:

1. If I use `Option1` - PlaneTypeTask table is not filled with an added PlaneType data.
2. If I use `Option2` - UNIQUE constraint failed exception is thrown.
3. If I comment both lines and use only `_context.SaveChangesAsync()` - no changes are saved to database at all.

So what is my mistake? Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE:** I've created a ConsoleApp to test my DbContext:

```
//emulate fetching my object from database on page load - OnGetShowTaskEdit
var CurrentTaskEditModel = new TaskEditModel();
using (var context = new PlanDbContext())
{
    CurrentTaskEditModel.Task = context.Tasks.Include(p => p.PlaneTypes).AsSplitQuery().First();
}

//emulate user edited Name on page
CurrentTaskEditModel.Task.Name = "Edited name";

//emulate saving object to database on post
using (var context = new PlanDbContext())
{
    using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            //emulate user added a PlaneType on page
            var planeTypeToAdd = context.PlaneTypes.Include(t => t.Tasks).AsSplitQuery().First();
            CurrentTaskEditModel.Task.PlaneTypes.Add(planeTypeToAdd);

            //NOT working - PlaneTypeTask table is NOT filled
            context.Attach(CurrentTaskEditModel.Task).State = EntityState.Modified;
            context.SaveChanges();
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

It has same problems like in my Web App - so looks like something is wrong with my approach.

I've expected auto-implemented many-to-many to just work without explicitly mapping the join table and directly working with it. What is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Arthur Vickers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2012410/arthur-vickers) (aka **ajcvickers**) provided a solution [on github](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/29901):

This needs improvement--see [#28005](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/28005). For now, the best thing to do
is attach the disconnected graph first, then mark entities as Modified
as appropriate, and finally make changes to the graph. For example:

```
context.Attach(CurrentTaskEditModel.Task);
context.Entry(CurrentTaskEditModel.Task).State = EntityState.Modified;
CurrentTaskEditModel.Task.PlaneTypes.Add(planeTypeToAdd);
```

This then generated the following SQL:

```
INSERT INTO [PlaneTypeTask] ([PlaneTypesId], [TasksId])
VALUES (@p0, @p1);
UPDATE [Task] SET [Name] = @p2
OUTPUT 1
WHERE [Id] = @p3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your Db context too please? From your models I can't see anything wrong with it.

There is a good example on the [Entity Framework Tutorial](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) website which seems to match what you're already doing. Hopefully your Dbcontext might hint at what's going on.

Comment: I've added DbContext code in my question. BTW that tutorial is about "classic" EF6, not "modern" EF **Core** 6 that I use. EF Core 5 and above has [auto-implemented many-to-many convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#many-to-many). I don't need configure it in `OnModelCreating` and it is working without explicitly mapping the join table.

Comment: My apologies, although it's classic, the fundamentals still remain with the models. It's true you don't need to do any classic stuff in the ModelCreating method.

Also I misread your question, I can see now that's a join table. 

I think the issue is because the context is treating it like a new entity and trying to insert it. The conventional way (albeit it's another DB call) is to fetch the PlaneType first from the database and assign the the updated tasks to the list on the PlaneTypes object. That way EF is tracking what's changed.

Comment: Are you talking about filling data from both sides? Get `planeTypeToAdd` object from database, then add `planeTypeToAdd` to `CurrentTaskEditModel.Task.PlaneTypes` list and after that add `CurrentTaskEditModel.Task` to `planeTypeToAdd.Tasks` list. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: Yeah so essentially you'll have the object coming in from your page, I believe this is called  "TaskEditModel" from your post? Secondly, retrieve the task from the Db, something like "var task = _context.Tasks.FindAsync(t => t.Id == taskEditModel.Id)". Then do... "task.PlaneTypes = taskEditModel.PlaneTypes". Finally save it with "_context.SaveAsync();". That way, you're retrieving the object from the database and loading it into context, assigning PlaneTypes a new list and Entity Framework should track the changes and make the necessary updates to the database.

Comment: To be correct object from page is called `TaskEditModel.Task` (because `TaskEditModel` contains some other properties). Name can also be edited on the form. So besides filling PlaneTypes collection with `task.PlaneTypes=TaskEditModel.Task.PlaneTypes` I will also have to do `task.Name=TaskEditModel.Task.Name`. My real Task class has over 20 properties and you advice me to fill them all, right? For me that looks like overkill - I hope there should be more simple solution. I already fill my object from database on page load - why it is not tracked by EF? Why do I need to load again before save?

Comment: [Arthur Vickers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2012410/arthur-vickers) (aka **ajcvickers**) provided a solution [on github](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/29901) - see accepted answer.